# I do not see the value after ajax procedure

Tags: jquery

This is using jQuery ajax and get data from php file.

I can see data that I want to have at first and second alert however, I do not know why I cannot see any value from the third alert.

```
function getMarkerContent(marker)     {
          // Fetch data from database          
          var ret = "<ul>";
      var temp = "";
      var process = "";

      $.get("../status.php", function (returnValue) {
          var json = eval("(" + returnValue + ")");
          $.each(json, function (key, state) {
              obj = state;
              ret += "<li>" + obj.member_id + ": " + obj.content + "</li>";
              temp += obj.member_id + ": " + obj.content + "\n";

          });
          process = processfunction(temp);
          alert(temp);  // first alert
          ret += "</ul>";
      });

      alert(process); // third alert
   }
  function processfunction(data) {

      alert(data);
      return data;  // second alert
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations! You just discovered why callbacks exist.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Your first and second alert are triggered within the `.get` `success` callback function, and thus are called only after the AJAX method returns a result.

Your third alert takes place outside of the callback, so it is fired before the AJAX method returns any data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So because third alert takes place outside of the callback, there is no way to use the data? I want it to return to another function.

Comment: Only code inside the "success" callback is guaranteed to run *after* the AJAX data is retrieved. That's what "asynchronous" means: the AJAX runs, and the rest of the code continues to run while you're waiting for it -- except for the callback.